# Have problems installing mod_python

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-python

I seem to have some problems installing mod_python with apache.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2
make
make install
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start
```

On the final line, I seem to get this error.

```
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Actually there are two errors. I think we could get rid of make_sock by committing out the listen port is. However I do not know what the hell when it means no listening socket available means

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the stupid questions, but (a) you are doing this as root, yes, and (b) apache had previously been shut down, yes?  If either of those two wasn't true, that error would be expected.

Comment: Both of these are true. Acutally I changed the port name in httpd.conf file. That somehow shut it up. However I still get Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'PythonHandler', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration. I wonder where my mod_python.so file is. I still do not see in in /usr/local/apache2/modules/. It is not even in /usr/lib/apache2/modules. How is mod_python.so even created?

Comment: Which distro are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running

> netstat -apnt | grep :80

To see if something else is running on port 80. Also, check your log location is writable by the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Quick digging up of a 10 year old question with no upvote and no accepted answer.

`mod_python` was abandoned almost a decade ago. It was removed from the default apache setup since apache 2.4.

Ironically this timeline is not far from when the question was opened. It might have been already dead back then. For historic reference, mod_python never came to supporting python 2.7, there are nasty crashes to encounter if you try to compile it and run non-trivial applications.

There are well supported native python web servers (gunicorn, tornado, bottle, flask to quote a few).

Older systems may run as fastcgi, which is fine and stable although very ancient, both apache and nginx can run fastcgi applications.